# Problem with bluetooth in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: bluetooth

I am a new user of Ubuntu and I am really fascinated by its performance. Coming to the question, I am facing some problems with the bluetooth connection. When I connect my mobile with the computer through bluetooth, and then click on 'Browse Device', the phone folder opens, but after 1 second, the folder gets closed by itself. But I am able to connect the internet through my phone. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can U mention which phone model U using? I can try to give U answer better.